# Error al reiniciar apache Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache

Tengo un problema con la conexión a Apache, luego de reiniciarlo con el comando `sudo service apache2 restart`,me da este error

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

y luego al entrar en localhost no me deja entrar y me da eror, cuando ejecuté `sudo journalctl -xe` me dijo lo siguiente pero aun así no encuentro el error, si pudieran ayudarme estaría muy agradecido

EDIT: ejecuté el comando `systemctl status apache2.service` y me aparece esto

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-10-17 12:20:34 -04; 29min ago
  Process: 21198 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 7385 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 23453 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1059 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

oct 17 12:20:34 pcarrasco systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
oct 17 12:20:34 pcarrasco apachectl[23453]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 47 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/cms.local.conf:
oct 17 12:20:34 pcarrasco apachectl[23453]: order takes one argument, 'allow,deny', 'deny,allow', or 'mutual-failure'
oct 17 12:20:34 pcarrasco apachectl[23453]: Action 'start' failed.
oct 17 12:20:34 pcarrasco apachectl[23453]: The Apache error log may have more information.
oct 17 12:20:34 pcarrasco systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
oct 17 12:20:34 pcarrasco systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
oct 17 12:20:34 pcarrasco systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

este es el contenido del archivo que segun me da el error

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
      ServerName sistemacasos.ac

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/proyecto/index.php

    <Directory /var/www/proyecto/index.php>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: En el log que colocas no hay información sobre el Apache2, te sugiero ejecutar : systemctl status apache2.service para ver los logs exclusivamente del apache.

Comment: ya lo ejecute y me aparece lo que coloque arriba

Comment: Listo, revisa el archivo /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/cms.local.conf en la linea 47 tienes un error, si necesitas ayuda con eso edita la respuesta y pones el contenido del archivo o simplemente la linea 47.

Comment: en la linea 35 solo aparece el cierre de la etiqueta de virtualhost

Comment: El log dice que el archivo  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/cms.local.conf tiene un error en la linea 47. pega el contenido completo del archivo en la pregúnta.

Comment: al final lo solucione eliminando los archivos cms.local.conf en sites-enabled y en sites-disables aunque no era lo que queria, puesto que estoy trabajando en laravel pero para acceder al sitio debo usar localhost/proyecto/index.php/sistema para acceder a la ruta ya que no he podido crear un virtualhost

Comment: En todo caso probablemente necesitas usarlo, si restauras el archivo y lo pegas en tu pregúnta te puedo ayudar.

Comment: añadi el archivo pero al hacerlo me sigue dando el problema en localhost

Comment: El archivo de localhost es otro.? el archivo que pusiste en el post no concuerda con lo que dice el Log. válida esa información.

Comment: Necesita " alredeador el path en <Directory >  como <Directory "/var/html">

Comment: al leer el error de nuevo lo modifique para vere si agregandole eso funcionaba ahora no me da el error de antes pero sigue sin funcionar el virtualhost

Comment: `/var/www/proyecto/index.php` no es un directory

Answer (score 0):

Esto es común debido a problemas en su configuración

puede ser la configuración del puerto

Bloquear en el [log file](https://blog.codeasite.com/how-do-i-find-apache-http-server-log-files/) (el paso se puede encontrar como `ErrorLog` en `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`)

o intente deshacer lo que cambió en los archivos de configuración hasta que encuentre el problema

Comment: busque la ruta y no la tengo uso ubuntu 18.09, cuando use el comando `sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` me dice que la ruta no existe

Comment: si está usando solo apache, lo encontrará en `/etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf/`

Comment: si lo está ejecutando con `lampp / xampp`, entonces será normalmente `/opt/lampp/etc/...` o en otras palabras `/{dir-to-stack}/lampp/etc`